# How to use linked resource with eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I found it very difficult to configure linked resource in Eclipse CDT.

Folder "`wspolne`" is located somewhere in the system, I'd like to use `.cpp .h` files from it in my current project, but avoid copying it.
From what I read about Linked Resources is a solution, but I can't build a projct :/

I followed [instuctions described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907275/in-eclipse-cdt-shared-resource-folder-that-is-built-differently-for-the-project) with out any result: What's wrong ?

Image that shows problem:

[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1629/eclipsen.jpg](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1629/eclipsen.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure linked folder are always [adequately indexed](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/771437/) by the CDT
(update October 2012, it has gotten better with recent CDT releases)

A workaround would be, as [in this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/68594/215191/#msg_215191):

> If you want CDT to manage the builds you need to move the sub-folders into there own project folder and create dependencies between them.

Comment: The links are broken, could you please fix them?

Comment: @ernesto first link replaced (I didn't found the original one), second link restored.